# Is there any way to restrict user from changing file extensions in Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7?

Tags: windows, group-policy, file-extension

For example, not allow users to rename  abc.doc to  abc.jpg? 
Is there any windows group policy for that?

Comment: Yes there is a group policy which can help you restricts users from creating certain file types. check the link and  let us know i it helps ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZr2f.png

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - Why didn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: because i am not sure if he is trying to do this locally or from a server

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - If this is about configuring a server it wouldn't be on topic anyways and should have been ask at [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: Thank you for your effeort. However, I am not concern about association. Indeed I am looking for a server setting to control rename of file extension - at least not display the extension in the first place. I will move the question to serverfault.

Answer (score -2):

No. Windows file permissions are not that granular. If a user has permission to rename a file they have permission to rename it to anything.

The closest you can do is prevent users from seeing file extensions in the first place ("Hide file extensions for known file types") and preventing them from changing that setting. However that only applies to Explorer and does not prevent them changing file extensions using a command prompt or another application that ignores the Explorer setting.

Comment: this is not correct. I have been to places where you cannot create files of certain extensions which includes renaming an existing one, downloading one or creating one

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: Preventing certain file types being created is not the same as preventing a user renaming a file to any other extension. The OP did not ask how to prevent certain file extensions being created.

Comment: It might sound incorrect technically but it is correct to an extent & 100% correct literally. Also that doesn't change your answer from being incorrect as i have clearly said that **there are policies that can stop users from creating files of certain extensions by making a new one, renaming an existing one or downloading**

Comment: What does this statement in OP's question mean ? **For example, not allow users to rename abc.doc to abc.jpg? Is there any windows group policy for that?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26189/discussion-between-the-it-guy-you-dont-like-and-qasdfdsaq).

Comment: I am sure everyone who has been in an office where they could not save files of certain extension by any means would find above comments funny + nostalgic

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: is there any domain group policy for  ("Hide file extensions for known file types") ? Because I will also try to close the cmd.exe loophole.